# Mobile Browsers are displaying breakpoint styles for 768px+ on smaller screen sizes (mobile)

Tags: css, google-chrome, firefox, webpack, twitter-bootstrap-4

Mobile browsers (chrome, ff, safari) are displaying a site's styles for tablet-size breakpoints from on my mobile phone? I'm using [Bootstrap 4](https://getbootstrap.com/) along with some custom styles.

From the desktop everything in Chrome, FF, and Safari work fine when resizing the screen. However the Chrome emulator and live (from my Pixel) are rendering styles for a 768px breakpoint. This can be seen here: [firstintreeservices.com](http://firstintreeservices.com/) from a mobile phone browser.

I've tried adjusting sass partial import order, removed the Bootstrap scss from my Webpack bundle completely and connected to the CDN. I still can't find a solution to this and have never encountered it before.

**Note:** I'm using a combination of Bootstrap's responsive utilities and my own responsive styles.

**UPDATE** This is a GoDaddy URL redirect/masking issue

The project directory/structure can be found in [this repository](https://github.com/first-in/First-In-Tree-Services).

```
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">
<meta name="description" content="">
<meta name="author" content="">

<!-- Bootstrap v4 -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-Gn5384xqQ1aoWXA+058RXPxPg6fy4IWvTNh0E263XmFcJlSAwiGgFAW/dAiS6JXm" crossorigin="anonymous">
<!-- Custom Styles & Overrides -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="styles/custom.css">

<title>First In Tree Services</title>
</head>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a GoDaddy URL redirect + masking issue.

Found the answer in GoDaddy's Community [here](https://www.godaddy.com/community/Managing-Domains/Forward-w-Masking-Disables-Mobile-Website/td-p/7793).

Answer (score 1):

as far as i can see in the website you linked to ( http://firstintreeservices.com/ ) there is no meta viewport like in your code here.

```html
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">
```

Comment: I just learned that a masked GoDaddy redirect only loads the sites desktop version. It doesn't redirect as expected w/ DNS.